# how to import a sheet from a specific workbook?

Tags: vba, excel, currency, finance

I am working on analyzing some data that is basically currency exchange rates and so forth. This data fluctuates daily. 
I want to create a workbook where one can select the date. Also, i will have a folder full of data from each date.
Based on the date selected, I would want to import the first two sheets from the file with the name matching the date.
Any help on how to do this in VBA would be very much appreciated. 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple worksheet copy like this

```
Sub Importsheet()

    Dim anotherWorksheet As Workbook
    Set anotherWorksheet = Workbooks.Open("some medium funny sheet path and name")
    anotherWorksheet.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    anotherWorksheet.Close (False)
End Sub
```

this is just example, you need to specify your workbooknames, and sheetnames/numbers and also where you wana to place them...